# Text to Speech in Mandarin for iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

Is there any Text to speech library for Mandarin language in iOS? Any idea? I was seeing OpenEars, but don't think it supports Mandarin. Does it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Nithin

Comment: Hi, OpenEars developer here. It is possible to do speech recognition for Mandarin in OpenEars, but it isn't yet possible to do text-to-speech.

Comment: Ohh..Any other library you know or have ever heard which supports Text to Speech in Mandarin?

Answer (score 1):

iSpeech has an iOS SDK, which is for free and has 2 Mandarin voices (male & female)

http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone

It has branding though: there’s an 'iSpeech' pop-up shown every time it synthesizes text.